# Javascript Generated Captcha

Tags: javascript, python, html, mechanize, captcha

If you guys go to [this](https://edit.yahoo.com/registration?.src=fpctx&.intl=us&.done=http://www.yahoo.com/) page, you will see a captcha. However, whenever I use Python's mechanize module to load up this page, I don't get the  tag in the HTML. This makes me think it is generated using Javascript. However, If I go to the page in my browser, I can "inspect element" and find the image tag. Do you guys know any way I can automate the task of fetching that captcha? I'm kind of at a loss here....

Thanks so much,

Justin

Comment: perhaps the tag is generated with javascript, but chances are the image is still generated server side, otherwise a bot could theoretically figure it out.

Comment: Is there anyway to grab that captcha? That you know of? I just need the image, nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

The captcha DOM elements are inserted via javascript and the captcha image itself is created server-side and then displayed in the page.

The only two ways to create the same captcha information yourself are:

1. Let the javascript in the page run and then somehow fetch the DOM elements that the javascript creates.
2. Reverse engineer their captcha insertion code and try to figure out what it's doing so you can run your own code to create something similar.

There are also at least a couple ajax calls involved in their captcha processing too.  Perhaps if you could explain what you're really trying to accomplish, we could offer some better ideas.  Hopefully, you aren't trying to automate the filling out of a captcha since its purpose is to prevent that.